# Why has one of my two propane fireplaces suddenly gone completely out?

Tags: fireplace, bedroom

I have two open propane fire places one in my livingroom & the master bedroom right beside the livingroom. I have been using them both with out the logs in the fire place for a month or so now, anyway the one in my bedroom just shut off the polit light an all, the one in the livingroom is still on, they both are running off the same 100 lb tank that is new. I have been using them for almost two months now & never had this happen. I need to know what is going on I have small children in my home & will need them for heat & I won't sleep well till I know for a fact what the problem is or if I should let someone trained to look at it, my old man says he can fix it but I am a mom like I said an I am going to worry. Please someone help me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Likely a bad thermocouple, but from here it’s hard to say.  Thermocouples are an inexpensive safety device.. they do wear out over time.  It’s designed to turn the gas off if the pilot flame gets blown out.

Answer (score 0):

Before I speak to the problem of the one fireplace not working let me say a couple of things.  First, these types of appliances; gas logs in open masonry fire places are some of the least efficient ways to heat a room.  The vast majority of what little heat they make goes up the chimney. In a given 24-hour period you could experience a net loss in heat to the space.  Second, those units should not be used without their logs in place.  The logs are an integral of the appliance and its safe burning. They are an approved appliance if they are used according to manufacturer's instructions.  With out the logs, they are not an approved appliance.  As to the malfunction in the bedroom unit, it is probably something simple to repair. And those units have layers of built-in safety. No cause for alarm.  Simply because it is not burning is no indication that it represents a hazard.  Without a standing pilot all the valves close to stop any flow of gas. You may just need to relight the pilot, after you get the logs set properly.

Comment: Not always true. [Ventless gas fireplaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=ventless+gas+fireplace)